# returning data from casperjs waitFor()

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I would like to have an indication for the result of `waitFor`. Consider the following code:

```
var success = false;
casper.waitFor(function check(){
    return isSuccess();
},function then(){
    casper.echo("Great succees");
    success = true;
},function fail(){
    casper.echo("Failure");
},2000);
console.log("Did we make it? "+success);
```

Unfortunately, even when `then()` executes, the global `success` seems out of scope and does not update to `true`. I also thought about maybe making `waitFor` return this flag, but this function seems to return a `casper` object.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

All the `wait*` functions as well as all `then*` functions are step functions. This means that the execution of the passed callback function is scheduled. They are essentially asynchronous.

When you call `waitFor` (or any other step function) inside another step function callback, those are scheduled for execution at the end of the current step function. This means that if you call the asynchronous `waitFor` and after that the synchronous `console.log`, the result will not be ready.

```
casper.then(function(){
    var success = false;
    casper.waitFor(check, function then(){
        casper.echo("Great success");
        success = true;
    }, onTimeout, 2000);
    console.log("Did we make it? "+success); // here: the none of the waitFor functions are executed yet
});
```

The same is true for the global case where the steps are not inside of other steps. What you can do, is to make the `console.log` asynchronous.

```
var success = false;
casper.waitFor(check, function then(){
    casper.echo("Great success");
    success = true;
}, onTimeout, 2000);
casper.then(function(){
    // here: the waitFor functions are guaranteed to have run
    console.log("Did we make it? "+success);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand that these functions are asynchronous callbacks. In reality, %100 of the times I've ran and tested this, I first got the `"Great succees"` on the console, before I saw `"Did we make it? false"` output so I was under the impression it's an issue with the scope, because the timing seemed Ok. I will try to implement it the way you suggested. Thanks again